# How to say "could you help me print this please?" in a polite way but not too formal?

Tags: conversation

I'm a home tutor to Korean kids and every week I need to ask the parents to print out study materials at home. I always text the parents through kakao by saying "한녕하세요~오늘 수업 재료를 프린트 좀 부탁드려요."  I'm not sure if it's the right way to express it. DO I need the 좀 in this sentence?

Any more natural ways of asking in this situation? Just would like to make it polite but not too formal. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Good afternoon!

"좀" is a kind of subtle word. I'm sure it will be generally okay to use, but some people will think they are given some commands and not like it. Well, this is just a rare case so please do not care too much about it.

Anyway, I think "안녕하세요~ 오늘 수업 자료 인쇄 부탁드릴게요 ^^" can be suitable for a message to parents. 자료 sounds better than 재료 because 재료 reminds me some raw wooden or metal materials to work with. The smiling emoticon, ^^, are often used to soften the tone.

Comment: is 프린트 this word used often also? Can I say 오늘 수업 자료 프린트 부탁드릴게요?

Comment: 프린트 is also definitely okay.